# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of block tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an infinite matrix where all the elements of the diagonal are given by the same $2 \times 2 $ real and symmetric matrix , and the elements of the supradiagonal and superdiagonal are the same and given by another $2\times 2$ real and symmetric matrix.

I.e.:
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B&A&B\\&B&A&\ddots\\&&\ddots&\ddots\end{bmatrix},$$
where $A$ and $B$ are $2\times 2$ and real symmetric.

Is it possible to obtain an expression for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix?

Comment: Cool question. I'd like to know the answer as well.

Comment: I edited your post to show the matrix using mathjax. I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your matrix X, then X is a block Toeplitz symmetric tridiagonal matrix ($X=T(B,A,B)$).

Author of https://doi.org/10.1080/09720529.2020.1854939 derived the eigenvalues of $T(B,A,B)$ in Theorem 4.1. According to this, the eigenvalues of $T(B,A,B)$ are equal to the eigenvalues of $A+2cos{\frac{j\pi}{N+1}}B$, in which N is the number of diagonal blocks and $j=1,2,\cdots,N$.

Let's define, $Z(j)=A+2cos{\frac{j\pi}{N+1}}B=\begin{pmatrix}
    z_1(j) & z_2(j)  \\
    z_2(j) & z_3(j)  \\    
  \end{pmatrix}$, which is a $2\times2$ matrix. The eigen values of $Z(j)$ are $\frac{z_1(j)+z_3(j)\pm\sqrt{(z_1(j)-z_3(j))^2 +z_2(j)^2}}{2}$.

Finally, by defining $A=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 & a_2  \\
    a_2 & a_3  \\    
  \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
    b_1 & b_2  \\
    b_2 & b_3  \\    
  \end{pmatrix}$ we get:

eig(X)=$\frac{z_1(j)+z_3(j)\pm\sqrt{(z_1(j)-z_3(j))^2 +z_2(j)^2}}{2}$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,N$, where $z_i(j)=a_i+2cos{\frac{j\pi}{N+1}}b_i$. In your case, N goes to infinity.